# What method does My Wallet use to encode messages in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain.info, message

What kind of protocol does My Wallet use?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Messages are stored in a database at blockchain.info (so that text should probably be changed). For a while it did [use the blockchain](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1159289#msg1159289) for storing messages but this was changed after concerns from a few of the core developers.

Concerns were expressed [by Matt Corallo here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1162381#msg1162381)

> Oh god, thats awful...that is quite possibly the worst way to
>   implement messages in terms of network load...

and [by Gavin Andresen here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1162402#msg1162402).

> Yes, please don't create lots of unspendable scriptPubKeys. There are
>   more prunable ways of embedding messages into transactions. And there
>   are even better ways of associating messages with transactions, so
>   only people involved with the transaction can read the message (if
>   that's desired).

[Here is the message](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1165261#msg1165261) that implementation was changed back to using a centralized database.

> Since a few developers have expressed concern I've changed the notes
>   back to the centralised database for now. I still think there are many
>   use cases where you might want to contact the owner of an address
>   without needing to know an email etc, a decentralised way to do this
>   would be great.