# Is a public message at blockchain.info embedded in the actual block chain?

Tags: blockchain

When sending a transaction using a wallet at blockchain.info you can add a public message. This message shows up when viewing the transaction at blockchain.info.

Is this message embedded in the actual block chain or is it just a record in the database of the server of blockchain.info?

Comment: Just recorded in the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It did for a few days, before the blockchain.info operator concluded blockchain bloat was not good for Bitcoin.  Now those are only stored on Blockchain.info hosts.

For more details, see:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg1165261#msg1165261
- https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4709/153

Comment: blockchain.info has removed this feature. there is no more public message notes.